# Null Reference Exception (object refrence not set)

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

having null reference exception. its a update code i am passing values from combobox to a local variable and then pass it into method.

```
pro_business sb = new pro_business();  //business layer class
string name = up_name.Text;  
sb.Ppro_name = name;
string type= type_combobox.SelectedItem.ToString(); //Having problem here!!)
string unit = unit_combobox.SelectedItem.ToString(); //Having problem here!!)
sb.Ppro_unit = unit;         
string message1 = sb.UpdateProductDetails(name, type, unit);
```

Comment: No items are selected?

Comment: @Athari they are selected still its showing same thing

Comment: Selected or not: have you explicitly checked whether SelectedItem is null?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the exception is that `SelectedItem` is null, e.g. if the user did not select an entry yet. If you are only interested in the text of the item, rather use the `Text` property. If you want to check that the user has made a selection, use the `SelectedIndex` property.

In order to solve this, this code should work:

```
if (type_combobox.SelectedIndex >= 0 && unit_combobox.SelectedItem >= 0)
{
    pro_business sb = new pro_business();  //business layer class
    string name = up_name.Text;  
    sb.Ppro_name = name;
    string type= type_combobox.Text; 
    string unit = unit_combobox.Text;
    sb.Ppro_unit = unit;         
    string message1 = sb.UpdateProductDetails(name, type, unit);
}
```

For details on `NullReferenceException` and on how to fix it, see this excellent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/4660186#4660186).